# Error al recibir Valors de DataSet

Tags: asp.net, base-de-datos, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp

DetalleCuentasPorCobrarDataSet(parametros) es un metodo en la que envio parametros, esta caso Fechas.

envio dos parametros de fechas y hace la consulta

al devolverme los valors tengo error, en (DetalleCuentasPorCobrarDataSet)

cuales son los parametros de ReportDataSource rd = new ReportDataSource(" ", ) *NOTA: no funciona el intellisense*

[image: ERROR EN LA IMAGEN]

```
public ActionResult ImprimeDetalleCuentasPorCobrarController(DetalleCuentasPorCobrarParam parametros, string id)
        {
            LocalReport lr = new LocalReport();
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reportes"), "DetalleCuentasPorCobrarReport.rdlc");
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                lr.ReportPath = path;
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Index");
            }
            ReportDataSource rd = new ReportDataSource("DetalleCuentasPorCobrarDataSet", DetalleCuentasPorCobrarDataSet(parametros));

            ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[2];

            lr.DataSources.Add(rd);
            string reportType = id;
            string mineType;
            string encoding;
            string fileNameExtension;

            string deviceInfo =
                "" +
                "" + id + "" +
                "8.5in" +
                "11in" +
                "0,787402in" +
                "0,787402in" +
                "0,787402in" +
                "0,787402in" +
                "";

            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streams;
            byte[] renderedBytes;

            renderedBytes = lr.Render(
                reportType,
                deviceInfo,
                out mineType,
                out encoding,
                out fileNameExtension,
                out streams,
                out warnings);


            return File(renderedBytes, mineType);
        }
```

Comment: ¿El método `DetalleCuentasPorCobrarDataSet` es auto generado?

Comment: es un metodo que envia parametros y recibe valores para mostrar

Comment: Sería bueno que lo agregues, de esa identificar dónde realmente está el problema.